# Elasticsearch raw field mappings for some records its fetching records but for some records it not fetching

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch raw field mappings for some records its fetching records but for some records it is not fetching records. Not sure why it is happening. for id 79 working fine, for id 80, not working & working for others one.

`{
"id": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"raw": {
"type": "keyword",
"normalizer": "normalizer"
}
},
"analyzer": "autocomplete"
}
}

API Call:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,   
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": "80"
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": []            
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [],
                "should": [],
                "must_not": []
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Expecting - Why it is behaving like this for 2 different data.

Comment: Use the `id.raw` field instead of `id`

Comment: But id is working for some other records, why it is not working for some records.

Comment: Did you test with `id.raw` which is a non-analyzed keyword field? `id` is a text fields, hence analyzed with your `autocomplete` analyzer, which I don't know how you've set up, so that's probably the reason

Comment: its not working if only 2 digit, if more than 2 digit is there its working on id field, instead of id.raw, So i have implemented id field everywhere. So i just want to know why it doesn't search on 2 digit without raw.